# Encode and decode Bitmap using Base64 in android

Tags: java, android

I want to encode and decode a bitmap image and save after encode bitmap image as a text file, but i fail to save it. Have any code can help?

```
public void encodeTobase64(Bitmap myBitmap2) {

    Bitmap immagex=myBitmap2;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;
    File myDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Message Conceal");
    String fname = ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);

    b = new byte[(int) file.length()];

    try {
        //convert file into array of bytes
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        // byte[] bFile;
        fileInputStream.read(b);
        fileInputStream.close();

        //convert array of bytes into file
        FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = 
              new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/User/Desktop/ImageDecryption/DecryptedImageData.txt"); 
        fileOuputStream.write(b);
        fileOuputStream.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
public Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length); 
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why are you trying to save in C:/? I guess you are using avd, right? Even so, I think you don't have the permission to access C:/ from Android.

Comment: `save after encode bitmap image as a text file, but i fail to save it.` Yes. But you are not encoding it either. Start to encode first. Is this code for an Android app?

Comment: public String encodeTobase64(Bitmap myBitmap2) throws IOException
 {
    
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    myBitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
     byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
     String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
     Log.e("Look",imageEncoded);
     return imageEncoded;

 }
encode Bitmap image code, this like that?